# Should we have tags for distinguishing between language design and language implementation?

Tags: discussion, tags

This site is about programming language design *and* implementation, which are different subjects. Do we think that tags to differentiate between the two are needed?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

I think that the design process is sufficiently different to the implementation process that it warrants two different tags, [design](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) and [implementation](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/implementation).

Comment: I'm not saying you're right or wrong, but if this idea was accepted, there would need to be some very clear community guidelines around what demarcates "design" from "implementation".

Comment: I *was* leaning toward "no", but then I asked this question: [Why was C implemented with a register preservation convention that seems to be far less efficient than its predecessor's?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-was-c-implemented-with-a-register-preservation-convention-that-seems-to-be-f). I was asking about actual implementation, but the immediate answer was about design. An [tag:implementation] tag might have helped. ¶ I see there *is* such a tag now, so I've just added it to my question.

Comment: Tags are a bit one dimensioned. I imagine there will be more specialised tags which are more suitable but where they don't (yet) exist these would be a good substitute.

Answer (score 3):

Those are more like meta tags, which tend to cause issues long-term. Meta tags should be avoided, tags that focus on the actual topic of the posts are much more useful.

Comment: The tag wiki on MSE says, "Meta tags are tags which describe something other than the question's content--such as the author's skill level, motivation, or current take on it. Alternatively, they may be ill-defined concepts which make consistent application of the tag difficult or impossible." Because language design and implementation are different topics, wouldn't "this question is about language design" vs "this question is about language implementation" describe the content of the question?

Comment: @Someone that's why I softened my statement a bit, it's not an unambiguous meta tag. But it is rather close as it would essentially mean that almost every question has one of these two tags, and that is just not particularly useful. If you want tags like this I think they would have to be more specific and cover smaller areas.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't say these are quite "meta tags" but rather tags that'd (potentially) be overly broad for the site. If a tag can be applied to nearly every question on the site, it probably isn't a good tag. It's much more useful to include tags for specific aspects of programming language design/implementation, rather than for "design" and "implementation" in general. (...On the other hand, the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site does have tags for "science" and "mathematics", the latter of which is one of the most used tags on the site...)

Answer (score 1):

> No

Those tags would be used way too often, so I think no. One would fit on every question.