# Can we burninate the language design tag? Should we reconsider our consensus about removing it?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, meta-tags, retagging

[Pretty similar to this other post,](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/424/can-we-burninate-the-implementation-tag) but I saw a few users who wanted one tag but not the other so here we are in 2 different posts. [A consensus was established **not** to have it.](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/should-we-have-tags-for-distinguishing-between-language-design-and-language-impl) And yet it exists and currently has a whopping 56 questions. So, either we should decide to allow this type of tag or burninate it now before more questions are added during the Public Beta.

Comment: That doesn't look like a consensus to me ─ there are two answers saying opposite things, on 5 and 4 votes respectively.

Comment: And theres a 2 vote answer agreeing with a 5 vote. So more think one than the other

Comment: The two people who upvoted that one could be two of the same people who upvoted the other one. You cannot seriously call this a consensus.

Comment: Also the votes on here... @kaya3-supportthestrike

Comment: "More think one than the other" is not what "consensus" means.

Comment: Fair enough, hence why I ask should we reconsider @kaya3-supportthestrike

Comment: No, this is the “we’ve had this consensus now let’s act on it” post @user16217248-OnStrike

Comment: meta meta question. What is the basis of voting to close meta questions rather than answering with a no if you disagree?

Comment: can you make a proper request to burninate the tag, like StackOverflow did?

Comment: We already had a discussion…now this is a call for action @justANewbie